# C++ function wrapper of a function with a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, cgal

I am trying to make a function wrapper that takes a function with 1 template argument and use it in another header file. Basically the main program computes certain variables that defines my_function, which is used to define a "criteria.h" header in CGAL. Here is "sizing_fun.h" that contains the function and the function wrapper:

```
template <typename Point_vec>
double my_function(double x, double y, Point_vec list_of_points)
{
  //use list_of_points
  return 4.0+(x*x+y*y);
}

template <typename FT, typename Point_2, typename Point_vec>
class FT_to_point_function_wrapper : public std::binary_function<Point_2, Point_vec, FT>
{
  typedef FT (*Implicit_function)(FT, FT, FT);
  Implicit_function function;
 public:
  FT_to_point_function_wrapper(Implicit_function f) : function(f) {}
  FT operator()(Point_2 p, Point_vec list) const { return function(p.x(), p.y(), std::forward<Point_vec>(list)); } //error line
};
```

In the "criteria.h", I use my_func as the function wrapper defined above. pcc is the Point_2 argument, and my_list is the Point_vec argument.

```
double local_squared_size_bound = my_func(pcc,my_list);
```

I go error messages:

```
sizing_fun.h:17: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick> > >' to 'double' in argument passing
```

So it looks like the Point_vec type is not passed along correctly.

I realized this post:
[C++ function call wrapper with function as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492029/c-function-call-wrapper-with-function-as-template-argument)
But I think it is different because its functions do not have a template argument.

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typedef FT (*Implicit_function)(FT, FT, FT);`

You declared that the function accepts the same type for all 3 parameters, and also returns the very same type.

Should have been `typedef FT (*Implicit_function)(FT, FT, Point_vec);`

Fix the signature of `Implicit_function`, and your problem should be gone.

In case this is at least C++11, you should also be preferring `std::function` over raw function pointer so that functions or lambdas with bindings / captures can be accepted.

`FT_to_point_function_wrapper::function` should be declared `const` as it is only set by initializer list in constructor. If using C++11, you may then also declare `FT_to_point_function_wrapper::FT_to_point_function_wrapper` to be `constexpr`.

`FT_to_point_function_wrapper::operator()` should be declared to be `const` as well.