# C++ function call wrapper with class member function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36493331/4984168) code but it does not work with class member functions. Is there a way to generate a wrapper for class member function and call it like wrapper for non-class member?

```
#include <functional>
template <typename F>
class wrapper;

template <typename F, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type execute_helper (F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)( std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
class wrapper <std::function<Ret(Args...)>>
{
    std::function<Ret(Args...)> m_f;
public:
    wrapper( std::function<Ret(Args...)> f ): m_f(f) {}
    Ret operator()(Args... args) const  { 
        return execute_helper (m_f, args...); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you even need `execute_helper`? Just write out `m_f(args...)`. Also, why wouldn't this work for member functions (What is the exact error you are getting, and the piece of code that produces that error)? And what does this wrapper do that `std::function` doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with member function is they need an object of the class to be called.

Supposing you can pass the object of the class, together with the pointer to the member function, to the constructor, I suppose you can write the wrapper as follows

```
template <typename Ret, typename Cl, typename ...Args>
class wrapper <Ret(Cl::*)(Args...)>
 {
   private:
      std::function<Ret(Args...)> m_f;

   public:
      wrapper (Cl cl, Ret(Cl::*m)(Args...))
         : m_f{ [=](Args... as) mutable { return (cl.*m)(as...); } }
          { }

      Ret operator() (Args... args) const
       { return m_f(args...); }
 };
```

The following is a full compilable example of use

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
class wrapper;

template <typename Ret, typename Cl, typename ...Args>
class wrapper <Ret(Cl::*)(Args...)>
 {
   private:
      std::function<Ret(Args...)> m_f;

   public:
      wrapper (Cl cl, Ret(Cl::*m)(Args...))
         : m_f{ [=](Args... as) mutable { return (cl.*m)(as...); } }
          { }

      Ret operator() (Args... args) const
       { return m_f(args...); }
 };

struct foo
 {
   long long bar (int a, long b, long long c)
    { return a+b+c; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo  f;

   wrapper<decltype(&foo::bar)>  wfb{f, &foo::bar};

   std::cout << wfb(1, 2l, 3ll) << std::endl;
 }
```

Observe that the example works for a not-const member functions.

For const member functions, you could need another wrapper

```
template <typename Ret, typename Cl, typename ...Args>
class wrapper <Ret(Cl::*)(Args...) const>
 {
   private:
      std::function<Ret(Args...)> m_f;

   public:
      wrapper (Cl const & cl, Ret(Cl::*m)(Args...) const)
         : m_f{ [=](Args... as) { return (cl.*m)(as...); } }
          { }

      Ret operator() (Args... args) const
       { return m_f(args...); }
 };
```

In both cases, you could improve a little the `operator()` adding perfect forwarding

```
  template <typename ... As>   
  Ret operator() (As && ... as) const
   { return m_f(std::forward<As>(as)...); }
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this code to use it inside class definition?

Comment: @TwaikYont - sorry... I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: I need to use wrappers inside class definition in *.hpp.

Comment: Something like class A : public B { wrapper<&B::foo> foo(&B::foo); } . I tried to write code using std::mem_fn and std::bind with placeholders but failed.

Comment: @TwaikYont - I suppose it's possible; but, in my example, you need also an object of type `B` initializing the wrapper.

Comment: Ok. I modified template to make it possible to declare wrappers outside function. But I have [https://gist.github.com/twaik/fca3c17307e160ea1cbbac9dcb435b04#file-gistfile2-txt](another problem). It has compile time errors while wrapper is declared inside class. Can you please help me?

Comment: @TwaikYont: You cannot use that syntax to initialize data member, you need `m{init}` or `m = init` instead of `m(init)` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bae8b6434729f16d).

Comment: *"you could improve a little the operator() adding perfect forwarding"*. In fact, it would even be required for case as `void (C::*)(std::unique_ptr<Obj>)`. 2 possibilities, template method (with SFINAE), or non template method and forwarding according to method signature (might produce extra move).